# Create cumulative distribution histogram for a given data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following pandas dataframe `df`:

```
    Bin Cum_val
0   0   0.39
1   1   0.63
2   2   0.76
3   3   1.00
```

I want to plot the cumulative distribution histagram (step-wise) that would have `Bin` values in the X axis, and `Cum_val` values in the Y axis.

I tried this approach (both with `cumulative=True` and `cumulative=False`, since my data is already cumulative), but I get `Cum_val` values on the X axis, not on Y axis:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=df.ix[:,1], normed=True,
                            histtype='step', cumulative=True)

plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(0, 1.05)
plt.title('cumulative step')

plt.show()
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to become clear about what a histogram is and how that relates to your data. What you're doing is trying to compute a histogram out of data that **already is a histogram**.

In that sense, matplotlib behaves correctly: In your array `0.39, 0.63, 0.76, 1.00` each value occurs exactly once. If you call
`plt.hist(x=[0.39, 0.63, 0.76, 1.00], normed=True, cumulative=False)`
without the `bins` argument, the four values will be distributed among the default 10 bins, producing bars of equal height in the plot.

I can only guess on what you're really trying to achieve - and that would be to create a simple bar plot of the values, like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

data = np.array([[0,1,2,3],[0.39, 0.63, 0.76, 1.00]]).T
plt.bar(data[:,0], data[:,1], 1, tick_label=data[:,0], align="center" )
plt.ylim(0, 1.05)
plt.title('cumulative step')

plt.show()
```